# How to enable DeferredLoading in EF1

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have seen how to enable deffered loading in EF4, but don't know how to do this in EF1 .net framework 3.5

Any idea?

Comment: @Mitch Wheat Here is a link for this option http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/05/12/sneak-preview-deferred-loading-in-entity-framework-4-0.aspx in Framework 4, but not sure where is this option in Framework 3.5

Comment: No. What have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not called deferred loading any more. It is called lazy loading (should be called transparent lazy loading) and it is only feature of EFv4. EFv1 doesn't support it. If you want to load some navigation property in EFv1 you must explicitly call `Load` method.

Comment: So by default in EF1, reference entities are not loaded automatically? And Lazy Loading is ON - right ?

Comment: EF1 reference entities are never loaded automatically. You must always call some method to get them loaded.

Comment: And can u pls refer some code how to load reference entities ?

Comment: There is no option to turn on or off lazy loading in EF1. That feature is only in EFv4 to control transparent lazy loading where relations are loaded automatically when first accessed.

Comment: Have you read my answer? Use `Load` method no navigation property to load it.

Comment: Oh .. I missed it. Thanks
When I say lazy loading in ON by default, I don't mean that we can turn it off too, but I meant that, default behavior of EF1 is like lazy loading is ON ( which can not be turned off )